# Should [bugs] tag be disallowed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I randomly found the [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs) tag.
It seems meaningless both relative to the submitter's code (of course there is a bug in it) and third-party code (only a bug if an answer says so).

I am not sure who has the permission and what the process for this, but I suggest to delete and block that tag.

Actually I just found a similar question, [Kill the [bugs] tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121184/kill-the-bugs-tag), however there is no authoritative answer on why it still exists.

Comment: @michaelb958 I specifically reference that question as not having an answer (only speculation/discussion of tag meaning). As per http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/ should I be able to ask a similar question as long as original one was not answered completely?

Comment: @AndreyShchekin If you think that question needs new attention, award a bounty.

Comment: @Bart great point and I haven't thought of it. I'll do that if this one is closed. but as a general policy it wouldn't work, as most people do not have enough reputation on meta to use this approach more than a few times.

Comment: @AndreyShchekin Done.